How would you do this using Combinatorics (Binom/Multinom)?
What is the coefficient of $x^n$ when opening the parentheses in the product $(1+x+x^2 +· · ·+x^n)^k$?
I use the stars and bars method to find it. then used the formula
$C(n+k-1, n)$ to do it; I know that $x^n$ is given by the ways to distribute the sum $n$ among factors.
After this, I'm not sure how to proceed.

What have you tried, where have you gotten stuck. Try to edit your post to include some work and context so that this question is more well received by other users of the site.

With your edit, you have said you have found $C(n+k-1,n)$.  If that is the answer, then what is your question to us?

My question is how can I do it. C(n+k-1,n) is used for find the combination
But after that idk how to proceed

$C(n+k-1,n)$ is the answer; you reach $x^n$ by taking some (or none) from the first bracket and similarly from each of the other brackets, and since you never take more than $n$ from any one of them your stars and bars argument works.  Slightly more generally, $C(m+k-1,m)$ is the coefficient of $x^m$ for $0 \le m \le n$ but not for $m>n$.

thanks for explaining that. Got it.

Welcome to MathSE.  This MathJax tutorial explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.
